Confusion over sticky element and relative element sibling
I have a very basic html:


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
      #nav {
        height: 50px;
        background-color: #333;
        position: sticky;
        top: 0;
      }
      #card {
        position: relative;
        background: linear-gradient(45deg, #f3ec78, #af4261);
        min-height: 1200px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="nav"></div>
    <div id="card"></div>
  </body>
</html>



First of all I know the solution is to place z-index to my nav element.
My doubt raises when my sticky nav element is placed under my card element when scrolling, but I'm not really sure about the reason why this is happening.
Mainly because "position: relative" itself doesn't create stacking context and I know that position: sticky creates a stacking context. I also know that my sticky element is working as expected the only problem is that is below the card element with relative position.
I asked chatGTP and it mentions something about layers that are not exactly the same as stacking context but I'm still pretty confused about it.
Does anyone has a logical explanation for this?
this happens in safari, chrome and firefox

You should set the position relative of the parent element, in your case body. e.g. body {             position: relative;           }

@Muhammad first, that doesn't work and second I'm trying to look for an explanation why this is happening

You are saying that position: relative does not create a stacking context but in the same document you have linked, it says it creates a stacking context.
"Element with a position value absolute or relative and z-index value other than auto."

But one solution to this issue is as I said in my first comment that make the parent element relative then it works.

Jose,
"sticky nav element is placed under my card element", that is the way elements are placed on a page. Your card comes after your nav in the html, so the card element will be on top of the nav if they exist in the same x,y plane on the page. Per MDM and the css spec:

"boxes lie along a "z-axis" and are formatted one on top of the other"

The fact that "sticky creates a stacking context", has no effect in this instance, as the nav does not have any children. Again per MDM:

"z-index values of its child stacking contexts only have meaning in this parent"

Hope this explains the behavior sufficiently for you.
